# Less & + & not expanding

Tags: css, less

[According to the docs](http://lesscss.org/#-advanced-usage-of-&) if I do something like:

```
.child, .sibling {
    .parent & {
        color: black;
    }
    & + & {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

I should get rules like this:

```
.parent .child,
.parent .sibling {
    color: black;
}
.child + .child,
.child + .sibling,
.sibling + .child,
.sibling + .sibling {
    color: red;
}
```

So I'm doing something similar:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  td, th {
    text-align: right;
    & + & {
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
}
```

But it's not working. Any ideas on why not?

### [DEMO](http://codepen.io/kolodny/pen/sIGve)

Comment: I think it's working just right, what output did you expect?

Comment: Wouldn't that be `table + table` and `table + .d`?

Comment: Yup, it's just like @Chad says... [This](http://sharetext.org/dAym) is the output

Comment: @scumah Sorry, I gave a bad example. I fixed the question and demo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works perfectly fine for me using http://winless.org/online-less-compiler this is the output:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table td,
table th {
  text-align: right;
}
table td + table td,
table td + table th,
table th + table td,
table th + table th {
  text-align: left;
}
```

I think the problem is you're using the feature `& + &` incorrectly as it produced `table td + table td` which translates to a `th` who has an ancestor `table` whose previous sibling is a `td` who has an ancestor `table`.

I assume you mean `table td + th, ...` which you should do by using `+ th, + td`

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  td, th {
    text-align: right;
    + th, + td {
      text-align: left;
    }
  }
}
```

Produces:

```
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table td,
table th {
  text-align: right;
}
table td + th,
table th + th,
table td + td,
table th + td {
  text-align: left;
}
```

Just to clarify, the reason it's not working as you thought is because `&` represents the current selector, *INCLUDING* everything before the 'current' one as well.